# How to move SMS to secure box in HTC

Tags: android

I'm making an Android program. It's SMS related. I have an HTC and since UI has secure box option to move SMS, I want to "move" to this folder in my program. Does anyone know how to do that? And of course validate if this feature exists before trying to move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. You need to update the SMS database and update the `htc_category` column to 1.

Just use contentResolver and uri `content//sms/` (like update read sms) and just update that column too.

Answer (score 0):

on the htc go to msg then on the top your going to see messages pass secure